# Получить возвращаемое значение через рефлексию

Tags: java

Есть класс `DimensionManager` и мне надо получить возвращаемое значение (`int`) метода с названием `getDimensionID`, который возвращает `id` измерения `OVERWORLD`.

Как это можно реализовать?

Смог найти только получение значений, которые принимает метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть у нас есть метод `int getDimensionID(Object o1, Object o2)`.
Тогда для получения типа его возвращаемого значения нам потребуется написать две строчки:

```java
Method method = DimensionManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDimensionID", Object.class, Object.class);
System.out.println(method.getReturnType());
```

Для вызова метода с помощью рефлексии вам потребуется следующая строчка:

```java
method.invoke(
/* имя объекта класса, содержащего метод, или null, если метод статический */,
/* аргументы метода */);
```

---

Если ваш класс - `enum`, то вы не можете создать его экземпляр, но вы можете получить доступ к одной из его констант. Если не получается напрямую, можно через рефлексию тремя способами (пусть одна из его констант называется `INSTANCE`):

```java
// 1 способ
DimensionManager.class.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE").get(null);
// 2 способ
DimensionManager.class.getEnumConstants()[0]; // в квадратных скобках порядковый индекс константы
// 3 способ
Enum.valueOf(DimensionManager.class, "INSTANCE");
```

Дальше просто пишете:

```java
System.out.println(DimensionManager.class.getMethod("getDimensionID").invoke(Enum.valueOf(DimensionManager.class, "INSTANCE")));
```

Если после этого у вас вылетают ошибки, скорее всего, вы неправильно указали путь к классу.

Comment: Это я знаю, но мне надо получить значение, которое он возвращает, а не тип значения. Сам метод выглядит так:
```public int getDimensionID() { return this.d; }```

Comment: @flawe а что вам мешает его просто вызвать?

Comment: Если бы. Попросту выскакивает ошибка ```NoSuchMethodException```. Код: ```System.out.println(dimManager.getMethod("getDimensionID").invoke(dimManager.newInstance()));```. dimManager: ```Class<?> dimManager = Class.forName("net.minecraft.server." + version + ".DimensionManager");```

Comment: @flawe если вы указываете правильное имя класса, то, скорее всего, ошибка в `getMethod`. Надо написать `getDeclaredMethod`, иначе вы не сможете найти любые методы, кроме публичных. И метод `newInstance` я бы на вашем месте не использовал.

Comment: даже если так, то мне выдает те же ошибки. Если не использую newInstance, то вызывается ошибка ```IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class```. Еще хочу дополнить, что ```DimensionManager``` является ```enum``` классом.

Comment: С проблемой разобрался. Спасибо за помощь.